# In activity tab, the site logo overlaps the time

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile

Here's the image:
[image]

*Using Ubuntu 14.4 with firefox*

Comment: On a side not: looks like Mozaz Goyz has been deleted across the network: http://stackexchange.com/users/6572288/mozaz-goyz?tab=accounts ;)

Comment: Can't see this on OSX Yosemite Chrome (for *my* activity)...

Comment: Can repro, but only if the time shown is a double-digit number of minutes. The extra width of the letter "m", as compared to "s", "h" or "d", is what pushes it over the edge.